# High CPU Utilization in Local Machine(VM) while executing test in Non-GUI Mode?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

The local machine (virtual machine) configuration is 16GB RAM, dual core processor. While executing the test with 10 vusers in non-gui mode the cpu utilization is hitting 100% and in gui mode the cpu utilization is 60%. The whole resources are used by jvm and not able to find the why cpu utilization is high on task manager.

Earlier old virtual machine configuration was same but in the new machine CPU utilization is hitting 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically 10 users can consume a lot of CPU if they're doing "heavy" stuff.

If you want to investigate further - Windows task manager won't tell you what exactly causes high CPU usage, you should take a look at Java profiler tool, one of best free options is [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/). Proprietary paid alternatives include [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/features/) and [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).

You can also ensure that you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

If you won't be able to figure out the root cause of the high CPU usage and optimize your test accordingly you will need to consider allocating another machine and [running your JMeter test in distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter).

Comment: Thanks for the update but getting High CPU Utilization on local Machine (VM) not on Application Server Side

Comment: @BhaskaraReddyDwarampudi Dmitri suggested using Java profiler to look for problems when running jmeter b/c jmeter is java app. He didn't mention Application Server side.

Answer (score 0):

Get your CPU information from the Hypervisor, not the virtual machine.   There is no guarantee that your VM numbers are correct.

Same holds true for the system clock, which will experience clock jump to sync up to the physical system clock.  This will result in higher averages, maximums, 90th++ percentiles and standard deviation measurements.   The only product that gets around this clock jump problem in VM environments is OpenText LoadRunner on VMWare.